# How to detect disconnected RTCPeerConnection

Tags: html, webrtc

I'm running WebRTC demo in my chrome browser and I can already set up a video conference.
However, if one of the peers disconnects (refreshes the browser for instance), I have no idea how to detect it on the other side (and maybe alert a "Peer disconnected" message)

I've noticed that after the peer is disconnected, I receive some `ice candidates`, but I can't find any attribute which would help me to discover that this is actually a disconnected event.

I have googled and found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/G5-U-lHWs10)

> This would be handled via the "disconnected" state for RTCIceConnectionState. It will trigger after some TBD (currently ~5s) delay of not receiving liveness checks or media from the remote side

But I just can't find this "disconnected" state in my other's peer object.

Can you give me some more hints on this one? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check this read-only attribute:

```
peerconnection.iceConnectionState === 'disconnected'
```

References:

- http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc.html#widl-RTCPeerConnection-iceConnectionState

Comment: is this working for you in Chrome or you just see this in the definition? Because for me, RTCPeerConnection doesn't have `iceConnectionState` but `iceState`, however if this happens, it says `closed` instead of `disconnected`

Comment: It works for me in Chrome but I use the beta release - tested with http://simpl.info/rtcdatachannel/

Comment: Be careful with this one, we've found that the disconnected state still results in false positives.

Comment: This `peerconnection.iceConnectionState` is not worked under firefox browser, how do we handle this property to firefox?

Comment: Any ideas what to do with Firefox?

Comment: I'm having the same problems with Firefox. It just does not change the state to "disconnected" or "closed", although the peer is not available anymore and the disconnected state is described in their docs. Strange. The only workaround I can think of is using either the signaling or the data channel to send pings around. But that's rather hacky, IMHO.

Comment: Perhaps use `RTCPeerConnection.connectionstatechange` ?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/connectionstatechange_event